# Debuging on real device (iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, debugging

A have a iOS-project that I send to my iPad. But when I'm trying to run&debug it on the device, I take error 
"The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. 
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile."

In my Entitlements.plist key "Can be Debugged" in state 'YES'. When I change it to 'NO' - I can send application to iPad, but I take error 
Error Starting Executable '$APPLICATION_NAME'
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process $PROCESS_NUMBER.
How can I resolve this problem?

P.S. I read similar question, but answers don't help me … (In most of question answer say to create Entitlements.plist file)

P.P.S. XCode 4.0, iOS 4.3

UPD: Problem was solved.
I created new provision file in certificate-development tab, revoke previous certificate and request one new. As result I have taken new certificate in what is written all provision files and two provision files - one for distribution and one for development.

Comment: You may want to delete the entitlements on the device and let xcode put them back on it, see if that fixes it.

Comment: Have you got it to work previously? If not, you need to check that the provisioning profile allows YOU to run the application, whether the app id (in the project plist) is compatible with the provisioning profile's, and if the device is registered for the provisioning profile.

Comment: How can i delete just entitlements? I'm trying to delete all application, but it doesn't help me …

Comment: to jbat100
Device is regestered in provision file. But I created provision file before changing my entitlements.plist.

Comment: May be I must to download provision file from tab "Development"?
But when i create it, download and add - i get error that XCode can't find correct private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved.
I created new provision file in certificate-development tab, revoke previous certificate and request one new. As result I have taken new certificate in what is written all provision files and two provision files - one for distribution and one for development.